# Editing Reference Styles in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, editing, style

Within the Symbol Selector > Referenced Styles

How does one edit (rename, delete, etc.) the referenced styles in ArcMap 10?

*Clarification*: I don't mean changing the look of the symbol using the "Edit Symbol" button. I mean editing the name or deleting one of the referenced styles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is some "hack" method. But check if it complies with licensing policy.

We can find ArcMap referenced styles in file `c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Styles\ESRI.style`.

It is standard ArcGIS style library file.

Soon, I have realized that it is actually MS Access file! Just change it's extension to .mdb and try to open it in Access.

You will find all styles and I believe you can make necessary modifications to it. Then again just change extension to .style

Comment: Thanks that worked. I am editing my own .style file not ESRI's so I am positive it's not against the licensing policy.

Comment: Esri published how to edit .style files using MS Access in 2007: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/10/30/tips-for-managing-style-files/, so there's no concern about contravening a "you agree not to reverse engineer" licensing clause. Redistributing the Esri produced symbols would be a different matter.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Style Manager** under **Customize**.
In your own custom style-list: enter the folders that are not greyed-out.
Here you will find your custom created styles.
Edit and delete at will.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete any ESRI provided styles, however you can copy and paste ESRI styles into your own .style using [Style Manager](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/09/28/symbols-and-styles-in-arcgis-10-0/).

Comment: Here you change only style which is saved in your Map Document (mxd) not the style in the library. And you can't change any of Esri referenced styles via Style Manager as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, just updated my answer.