# Ordnance Survey Northern Ireland OSNI .qml file for large scale vector data?

Tags: united-kingdom, qml

I am a new QGIS user, having moved across from Arc. I have access to OSNI (Ordnance Survey Northern Ireland) data and to .lyr files associated with them, but has anyone created a .qml file for the large scale vector layers?

I am reluctant to go through the process of creating a style from scratch if it's already been done!

Comment: See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71719/converting-using-arcgis-style-file-for-in-qgis-qml-or-sld) for a possible work around.

Comment: Thanks... option 2 seems the more attractive option but when I go to the homepage of the Arc to SLD software it says it creates the SLD from a running Arc Project, not a .lyr?